# What is the difference between Banath and Kalkin on Midkemia?

Tags: raymond-e-feist, riftwar-cycle

Several times during the Riftwar series, and I've especially spotted it in the Darkwar Saga and onwards, whenever Banath is mentioned the speaker clears things up by also naming Kalkin and vice versa. Why is this? Is there some kind of distinction between the two or are they just two names of the same god used in different regions or by different people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official Raymond E. Feist website](http://www.crydee.com/raymond-feist/encyclopedia/riftwar-cycle/4789/ban-ath-dav-lu), the names are essentially interchangeable. One is a translation of the other:

> **Ban-ath (Dav-lu)**
>   AKA (translation): Bannath, Kalkin
>   Category: Lesser God
>
> *The artful dodger; the prankster; the night walker; the silent thief of precious commodities. God of Pirates. God of Thieves, Liars, and Cheats*

This is backed up in the text of [Wrath of a Mad God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrath_of_a_Mad_God). It's not entirely clear which race named him Kalkin, and he doesn't seem overly concerned either way:

> ‘Ban-ath,’ said Pug.
>
> ‘Of if you prefer Kalkin, Antrhen, Isodur, or any number of other
>   names humanity inflicts on me – Coyote is one of my favourites – but
>   no matter the name, I am myself

Answer (score 0):

They are just different names for the same God.

It also makes sense in a way that the trickster God would have a variety of pseudonyms